# KnockoutJS Binding a checkbox with both "checked" and "click" bindings causes unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js

here is the code I've been working on.

Javascript:

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

    self.isChecked = ko.observable(false);

  self.testing = function(){
    console.log("hello from testing");
  }
}

var app = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(app);
```

And here's the html:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <button data-bind="click: testing" type="button">Something</button>
    <input data-bind="checked: isChecked, click: testing" type="checkbox" />
    <input data-bind="checked: isChecked" type="checkbox" />
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm looking to accomplish is that I want a checkbox, whose value is data-binded to a variable in my model and updates accordingly. And at the same time, whenever a user clicks the checkbox to change its boolean value, I want a function to be executed AFTER the value is changed in the model and the checkbox is updated.

I have two buttons data-binded to the same value just for testing purposes. When I click the checkbox that is binded with `click` to `testing`, its checkmark doesn't change, but the function executes correctly. However, the other checkbox DOES indeed update to reflect the changes in the model when the button is clicked.

<s>What is happening that causes this behavior, and how could I write a better solution to achieve what I'm looking for?</s>

---

EDIT: So apparently, by adding a `return true;` to the function, I managed to... arrive at the intended behavior?

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.isChecked = ko.observable(false);

  self.testing = function(){
    console.log(self.isChecked());
    console.log("hello from testing");
    console.log(self.isChecked());

    return true;
  }

}

var app = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(app);
```

The question is then, why does this happen, and is it safe?

Comment: Reading the documentation helps. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-3-allowing-the-default-click-action

Comment: @Tomalak I should've paid more attention to the documentation, it answered exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the time you needed to write this (definitely well put-together) question you could have read it multiple times over. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So, in addition to what @Tomalak mentioned, if you want to trigger a function when the checkbox value is changed, you can [`subscribe`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) to the `isChecked` observable

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.isChecked = ko.observable(false);

  self.isChecked.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    // this gets executed every time "isChecked" changes
    console.log(self.isChecked());
    console.log(newValue);
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="checked: isChecked" type="checkbox" />
```

The advantage of using `subscribe` over `click` binding is that, this function gets triggered even when you set the value of checkbox programmatically like this `self.isChecked(false)`